# Filter data before onSaveAll execution

Tags: spring-boot, javers

I have a spring-mongo application with javers integrated which provides @JaversSpringDataAuditable annotation. Now the problem is for some of my repositories i do not want to save all data for audit which means i want to filter the data before JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.onSaveAllExecuted() is called. 
Since, this is an advice , i cannot write another advice on top of it. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to do it. With Javers 5.9.4 and above , you can now write custom aspects to filter data before javers audits it. Read it here : https://medium.com/@ketannabera/auditing-in-java-application-using-spring-boot-mongodb-part-3-9729eb5ba62b